# Python Timestamp became random numbers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

I have a question about pandas timestampe and sincerely hope you can help me with:

I have 2 list of times (qr_datelist, nonqr_datelist), they could contain none:

```
print(qr_datelist[1])
```

> None

```
print(nonqr_datelist[1])
```

> 2018-06-29 00:00:00

```
print(type(nonqr_datelist[1])) #this is a pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

> 

then i used `all_datelist = list(np.where(qr_datelist.isnull(), nonqr_datelist, qr_datelist))` to make new list (all_datelist) to fill the list with nonqr_datelist when qr_datelist is None.

then when i print `all_datelist[1]`, i got

> Out[73]: 1530230400000000000

where i know all_datelist[1] should be from nonqr_datelist, which is 2018-06-29 00:00:00. I'm a little confused by it. Please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is commend bug  for numpy handle this type issue

Comment: Thanks W-B for commenting! Any idea to solve this? Really appreciate it!

Comment: a list object has no attribute called `isnull`. you can try `list(np.where(qr_datelist.isnull(), nonqr_datelist, qr_datelist))` instead.

Comment: Hi @Naveen, thanks for your reply. I think `list(np.where(qr_datelist.isnull(), nonqr_datelist, qr_datelist))` is what i have right now, could you kindly help me a little more on this please? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there is no `isnull` function. You can use list comprehension to create a new list which has the date from `nonqr_datelist` whenever the values in `qr_datelist` is `None`.

```
new_list = [np.where(item is None, nonqr_datelist[qr_datelist.index(item)], qr_datelist[qr_datelist.index(item)]) for item in qr_datelist]
```

Comment: Thanks @Naveen, it was very helpful!!